# How to get the call waiting state of a new incoming call during a phone conversation?

Tags: android, call, busy-waiting

Based on my requirement i need to track all incoming phone calls.

i successfully track the incoming and missed calls through broad cast receivers.

But i didn't get the call waiting state.In that state i missed to track the both incoming numbers.

If any one how to get waiting call state ,please reply me.

thanq

Answer (score 0):

The actual implementation depends on the specific case, but the answer is: **use [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) and [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int))** in a background thread.